# Tesseract RuntimeError: Failed recognize picture

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am new to tesseract and I got this error when trying to use an external trained data set.

```
tesserocr.pyx in tesserocr.image_to_text (tesserocr.cpp:20994)()
RuntimeError: Failed recognize picture
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot it. The issue is with the external library but beyond that, I don't know.  Any guidance is appreciated.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, x86_64, Python 2.7 with Tesserocr wrappers.  The external library is from: https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr.

I just pasted the letsgodigital.traineddata file into:

```
/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata
```

Code:

```
import tesserocr
image = Image.fromarray(im)
print tesserocr.image_to_text(image, lang = 'letsgodigital', psm=8, )
```

Language check

```
print tesserocr.get_languages() 
(u'/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/', [u'letsgodigital', u'equ', u'osd', u'eng'])
```

Running the code with the default english library works

```
print tesserocr.image_to_text(image, lang = 'eng', psm=8, )
```

Tesseract version information:

```
tesserocr.tesseract_version()

u'tesseract 3.04.01\n leptonica-1.73\n  libgif 5.1.2 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.4 : libopenjp2 2.1.0\n'
```

Comment: Any comment to my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The error `RuntimeError: Failed recognize picture` says the image is unable to load. You may try below to ensure the 'eng' works first. Then specific the customized language to your 7-segment digit display.

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('english_text.png')
digits = tesserocr.image_to_text(image)  # print ocr text from image
```

Also set `TESSDATA_PREFIX` for trained language data path as below if you haven't done that.

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata
```

Hope this help.

**UPDATE:**

Tested the below image cropped from the [sample](https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr/blob/master/img/example.png),

[image]

in `Windows 10` with `Tesseract 4.0.0a`, the output is correct.

[image]

For the sake of testing, if the above image doesn't work in your machine, you may try the *edited image* below which has more top and bottom margins. This one works even with the default `--psm 3` and `--oem 3` modes.

[image]

Comment: I did both these things as evident from the statement "Running the code with the default library works..." but I am very willing to try any new suggestions.

Comment: @DanGoodrick updated the Answer.  Will try to test it with `tesserocr` (`tesseract 3.04`) in `OSX` if time permits.

Comment: I couldn't get the 'letsgodigital' library to load on my machines (linux and windows 7).  However, I was able to accomplish the same task by using KNN.  I will mark my question as answered if I could figure out what you did differently (or why my code didn't work).